# How to make search for posts using get method?

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, loop, search

So I am building a WordPress theme for myself to meet my needs, so what I am looking for now is make a search using a get method in PHP.

If my URL is something like this :

```
http://www.example.com/search.php?string=Bananas+and+apples
```

In my `search.php` I would like to do something like this:

```
string = $_GET["string"];

 $fruits_args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'fruits',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'cat'           =>  'fruits'
); 
 $fruits = new WP_Query($fruits_args);
```

So how do I making the loop related to the string that I get from the the get method?

Comparing the search string the the post type, category and post title would be enough.